# Tkinter floating optionmenu

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, optionmenu

About 2 years ago, I made a program that used optionmenus in Python 3.2. Between then and now, I used 3.3.2, and 3.3.4. I ran that program a few days ago with 3.3.4, but the optionmenu was disattached from its button. Instead of the menu being anchored to the button, it was suspended about half a screen below the button. Then I ran it with 3.2, and got the same result. However, I ran it with 3.3.2, and got the expected result with the menu anchored to the button. Is there some reason for this?

Comment: You may also want to ask it in the Tkinter mailing list.